# Database recursive error

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview, android-arrayadapter

I've one database with contacts.
From my main activity i call a function called recuperarTodosContactos where i get all the contacts, and put them in a list-view.

The problem I'm facing is that if the database is empty, recuperarContactos fails and the list-view is not shown ( crashes). This doesn't happen if i have the list-view with contacts and begin to delete them till there's no contacts and list-view is empty.

So i need to enter at least one register... ideally oncreate.But it gives me an error of recursive getWriteble database.

```
01-29 12:25:53.851: E/AndroidRuntime(583): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity Component-info{com.example.informacion/com.example.informacion.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWritableDatabase called recursively
```

My database ( the important things):

```
  public BaseDatosContactos(Context context) {
        super(context, NOMBRE_BASEDATOS, null, VERSION_BASEDATOS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(CREAR_TABLA); //db.execSQL(TABLA_CONTACTOS);
        //addContacto(new contactoAgenda("Belen", "c/ Diego Madrazo","1", "belen@gmail.com",true, true, false, false, false,"Familia", R.drawable.hulk));
        insertarContacto("Belen", "c/ Diego Madrazo","1", "belen@gmail.com",1, 1, 0, 0, 0,"Familia", R.drawable.hulk);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLA_CONTACTOS);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLA);
            onCreate(db);

    }

    public void insertarContacto ( String nombre, String direccion, String telefono, String email,int miembrofacebook, int miembrotwitter, int miembrogoogle, int miembrolinkedin, int sexo, String tipocontacto, int imagen){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        if (db != null) {
            ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
            valores.put("nombre", nombre);
            valores.put("direccion", direccion);
            valores.put("telefono", telefono);
            valores.put("email", email);
            valores.put("miembrofacebook", miembrofacebook);
            valores.put("miembrotwitter", miembrotwitter);
            valores.put("miembrogoogle", miembrogoogle);
            valores.put("miembrolinkedin", miembrolinkedin);
            valores.put("sexo", sexo);
            valores.put("tipocontacto", tipocontacto);
            valores.put("imagen", imagen);
            //db.insert("contactos", null, valores);
             try {
                    db.insertOrThrow(TABLA, null, valores); //TABLA por "contactos"
                } catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Fallo en la insercion: seguramente la clave ya existe.");
                    //return false;
                }

        }
        db.close();   
    }



public ArrayList<contactoAgenda> recuperarTodosContactos() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        ArrayList<contactoAgenda> lista_contactos = new ArrayList<contactoAgenda>();
        String[] valores_recuperar = {"nombre","direccion","telefono","email","miembrofacebook","miembrotwitter","miembrogoogle","miembrolinkedin","sexo","tipocontacto","imagen"};
        Cursor c = db.query("contactos", valores_recuperar, null, null, null, null, null, null);
       if (c==null){
        //perhaps something here when database table is empty ??   
       }
        c.moveToFirst();
        do {
            contactoAgenda contactos = new contactoAgenda(c.getString(0), c.getString(1), c.getString(2), c.getString(3),c.getInt(4), c.getInt(5), c.getInt(6), c.getInt(7),c.getInt(8), c.getString(9), c.getInt(10));
            lista_contactos.add(contactos);
        } while (c.moveToNext());


        db.close();
        c.close();
        return lista_contactos;
    }
```

Any ideas or help please ?: Listview with image and two texts that crashes when the arraylist obtained from recuperarContactos is empty ( there are not any contacts in the database). This occurs first time..

```
public contactoAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<contactoAgenda> datos) {
                super(context, R.layout.listview_item, datos);
                // Guardamos los par�metros en variables de clase.
                this.context = context;
                this.datos = datos;
            }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View item = convertView; 
            contactoHolder holder;

            if (item == null) {
                item = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listview_item,
                        null);

                holder = new contactoHolder();
                holder.imgContacto = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.imagenContacto);
                holder.tvMail = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvMail);
                holder.tvNombre = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvNombre);

                // Almacenamos el holder en el Tag de la vista.
                item.setTag(holder);
            }

            holder = (contactoHolder) item.getTag();

           holder.imgContacto.setImageResource(datos.get(position).getDrawableImageID());

            holder.tvNombre.setText(datos.get(position).getNombre());
            holder.tvMail.setText(datos.get(position).getDireccion());


            return item;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

In the onCreate you are given a db connection, you then call insertarContacto which creates an additional db connection. You should give the pre-existing connection to your insert function.

Comment: how ?? I call something db.insertOrThrow(TABLA, null, valores); where valores is  a contentvalues with my contacto. Is there any solution to the listview crash ?? It should show an empty listview if database is empty...Thanks

Comment: If the database is empty, it will work, but if the database DOESN'T EXIST, then it will try to create it, thus the error. As to how: see the way `onCreate` receives `SQLiteDatabase` as a parameter? Do the same for `insertarContacto`.

Comment: id say: db.execSQL(CREAR_TABLA); db.insertOrThrow(TABLA, null, valores);... so if database doesnt exists would create database and then insert the contacto...I dont understand about insertarContacto... you mean to add a SQLiteDatabase parameter ???

Comment: At any time you invoke a database function, if the database is not available on the device, it will be created at that point. What I mean you should do is : change `public void insertarContacto ( String nombre, ...){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        if (db != null) {` into `public void insertarContacto (SQLiteDatabase db, String nombre, ...){
        if (db != null) {` and remove `db.close();` from the end.

Comment: is there a way to prevent the listview to crash when database is empty ? First time ?''

Comment: It **doesn't** crash because the database is _empty_. It crashes because you have _two_ database connections at the same time when it tries to **create one** for the first time.